# Regex return only non empty after substitution

Tags: regex, pcre

Given this text string of `;` delimited columns:

```
a;; z
z;d;hh 
d;23
;;io;
b;b;12

a;b;bb;;;34
```

This regex

```
^(?:(a|b|z)(?:;|$)([^;\r\n]*)(?:;|$)([^;\r\n]*)(?:;.*)?|.*)$
```

with this substitution `$3` will return the 3rd column, if it exists, from lines whose first column is `a`, `b` or `z`, as shown in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ymHbvO/2)

My question is, how to return only the non-empty lines, as in:

```
    z
hh 
12
bb
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You need to filter those out after substituting. A substitution either replaces something or it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may still do that with a plain regex: you just need to re-arrange your two alternatives in the regex pattern and add an optional line break pattern at the end.

Your pattern has the `^((O)(N)(E)|.*)$` structure, so the second alternative matches the whole line if the first one does not match, but both alternatives will stop at the line end (you are using the multiline flag, so `$` matches all positions before a line break char or end of string). So, you need to convert it to `^(?:(O)(N)(E)$|.*$\R?)`:

```
^(?:(a|b|z)(?:;|$)([^;\r\n]*)(?:;|$)([^;\r\n]*)(?:;.*)?$|.*$\R?)
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mEHtDx/1), in the regex101 tester, note the use of `g` and `m` modifiers.

So, in general, the pattern is

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (so that `^` could be applied to both alternatives):

  - `(a|b|z)(?:;|$)([^;\r\n]*)(?:;|$)([^;\r\n]*)(?:;.*)?$` - your specific pattern capturing necessary substrings, up to the end of line/string
  - `|` - or
  - `.*$` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the 
    line/string end (`$`), and then
  - `\R?` - an optional line break sequence
- `)` - end of the group.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, as always very insightfull. I have a question, you said: `...(you are using the multiline flag, so...` Is there a way to do this without this flag? If so, would there be any advantage?

Comment: @fionpo Yes, but that [looks even uglier](https://regex101.com/r/mEHtDx/2).

Comment: Hello @Wiktor, please see this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mEHtDx/3) I added the 3 line `z;` and now there is an empty line in the result. I understand that the 3rd column is empty in this matching line. Still would like to not get the empty line in the result. I suspect that something must be changed here `(?:;.*)?$|.*$\R?` but I couldn't quiet pinpoint what it is

Comment: @fionpo If you require 3 groups to be present, if they are obligatory, then remove the optional groupings, `^(?:(a|b|z);([^;\r\n]*);([^;\r\n]*)(?:;.*)?$|.*$\R?)`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mEHtDx/4).

Comment: Thanks again @Wiktor For completion I added an empty line at the beginning and at the end [here](https://regex101.com/r/mEHtDx/5). The one at the end, shows in the result. Any suggestions how to get rid of this one

Comment: @fionpo Use `^(?:(a|b|z);([^;\r\n]*);([^;\r\n]*)(;.*)?(?:\s*\z|$)|.*$\R*)`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mEHtDx/6).